# How to mock function call inside a function in jasmine

Tags: jasmine

I would like to mock privateObj.checkstatus(request) while calling getState

```
    var privateObj = require('somepackage')
 module.exports = {  

    getState: function(req, res, next, logService) {        
        var request = {
            url: 'www.google.com'
}
        var status = privateObj.checkstatus(request);
      if(status=='123')   {   console.log(status);   }   logService.info(logMsg);
    enter code here
        res.send(status);

    }}
```

Comment: I do not understand, what you want to do? What is your testcase? Remember: first write the test, then the code.

Comment: Testcase will be test getState function and mock the checkstatus method